# Get user info from authentication panel in Firebase console

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

So I notice in the Firebase console, there's a panel called "Authentication" that contains a list of users. Every user has four pieces of information: Identifier, Provider, Created, Signed in, and User UID.

I'm wondering if there's a way you can programmatically access this information, while the user isn't signed in.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes  you can access those values using several methods. In order to get the provider, i suggert you using this code:

```
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
if (firebaseUser != null) {
    for (UserInfo userInfo : firebaseUser.getProviderData()) {
        if (userInfo.getProviderId().equals("facebook.com")) {
            Log.d("TAG", "User is signed in with Facebook");
        }

        if (userInfo.getProviderId().equals("google.com")) {
            Log.d("TAG", "User is signed in with Google");
        }
    }
}
```

There also other methods which are very useful: `getUid()`, `getDisplayName()`, `getEmail()`, `getPhoneNumber()` and so on. please take a look at [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser).

As a conclusion for this question, there's no way in which you can call another method to get the email address of an user. What can you do in stead, you can create a `users` section in your `Firebase database`, store all data you need and than just query it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: What if I wanna get the `providerData` of a user who isn't currently signed in?

Comment: What do you mean with `providerData`? Please see my updated answer, reagrding outher methods.

Comment: Oh sorry, what I meant is how can I call a function such as `getEmail()` from a user object that isn't signed in? In other words, how do I get that info without calling `getCurrentUser()`?

Thanks.

Comment: There's no way in which you can call another method to get the email address of an user. What can you do in stead, you can create a `users` section in your Firebase database, store all data you need and than just query it.

Comment: Alex: please update your answer with the information from the latest comment, since right now it doesn't answer the question. @Daniel: you nowadays **can** [get user information for a specific user (by their UID)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data) that isn't signed in when using the Firebase Admin SDK. This is meant for use in trusted environments (e.g. a server that you control, Cloud Functions), not directly in application code. If you need to show the info in the app, use the approach Alex mentions.

Comment: Done Frank. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have found in documentation something like this:
[Documentation about admin.auth().listUsers(...)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth.html#listUsers)

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users

```
admin.auth().listUsers(maxResults, pageToken);
```