# Firebase: How to revoke access to a Google account that is not logged in

Tags: android, firebase, google-authentication

I'm using Google authentication for my Firebase app, so I use the `GoogleSignInClient` to first generate a token and then log into Firebase with that.

Once that is done, Firebase now has its own token, and the app now runs happily after that without ever having to use Google's authentication again.

I want to give users the ability to revoke access to the app, but `GoogleSignInClient.revokeAccess()` returns `SIGN_IN_REQUIRED`, so I would first have to show the UI to let the user log in so I can revoke access (`silentSignIn()` is not enough).

This is confusing for the user - the user thinks they're logged in thanks to Firebase, so now showing a login UI just so they can revoke the access appears weird. I understand that Google's auth and Firebase's auth are separate, but is there an easy way to revoke access to the underlying Google account without resorting to the weird "log in to revoke" pattern?

Edit:

To clarify what I'm doing - this is basically the code being called when I'm trying to revoke. At this point, the user has had a valid Firebase authentication potentially for days or months.

```
 GoogleSignInOptions gso =
     new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
     .requestIdToken(clientId)
     .requestEmail()
     .setAccountName(emailAddress)
     .build();

 GoogleSignInClient signinClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(context, gso);
 signInClient.revokeAccess();
```

Comment: Check this out: https://androidwave.com/google-sign-in-using-firebase-android/

Comment: @code Thanks. If I read this code right, it requires you to log in every time you use the app, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Once you are logged in, FirebaseAuth stores that data for you. I don't think it requires you to log in every time you open the app. Are you sure this is what is happening?

Comment: @code That's the point of my question. I does not require a log in again, which is why I can't easily revoke the Google (not Firebase) sign-in access without requiring the user to sign in first, which is a weird user experience.

Answer (score 0):

> Firebase now has its own token, and the app now runs happily after that without ever having to use Google's authentication again.

That's correct, once you are authenticated to Firebase using Google credentials, there is no need to authenticate again to Google, nor to Firebase unless you are explicitly sign-out.

> I want to give users the ability to revoke access to the app, but GoogleSignInClient.revokeAccess() requires that you're signed.

In this case, revoke the access only when the user is signed in.

> I would first have to show the UI to let the user login so I can revoke access (silentSignIn() is not enough).

I'm not sure why would you need to show the UI, the user is still authenticated. As long as the user is authenticated you can revoke the access as needed.

> the user thinks they're logged in thanks to Firebase, so now showing a login UI just so they can revoke the access appears weird.

No, they are actually logged in. You didn't mention in your question that the user has explicitly requested a sign-out. As long as no sign-ed out operation was involved, the user will remain authenticated.

> I understand that Google's auth and Firebase's auth are separate

Yes, that correct. You need to sign-in both (Google and Firebase) in order to use this kind of authentication, as you also need to sign-out from both services.

> is there an easy way to revoke access to the underlying Google account without resorting to the weird "log in to revoke" pattern?

There is no need for any UI to revoke the access. Keep your user logged-in and revoke the access while it's authenticated.

**Edit:**

From the [GoogleSignInClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInClient#silentSignIn()) docs, regarding the SIGN_IN_REQUIRED error, it says:

> You can get from apiException.getStatusCode() the detailed error code e.g. GoogleSignInStatusCodes.SIGN_IN_REQUIRED means user needs to take explicit action to finish sign-in; Please refer to GoogleSignInStatusCodes Javadoc for details.

Going to the Java docs of [SIGN_IN_REQUIRED](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes#SIGN_IN_REQUIRED):

> The client attempted to connect to the service but the user is not signed in. The client may choose to continue without using the API. Alternately, if Status.hasResolution() returns true the client may call Status.startResolutionForResult(Activity, int) to prompt the user to sign in. After the sign in activity returns with Activity.RESULT_OK further attempts should succeed.

So most likely you are getting that error because of the use of silentSignIn().

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I forgot to specify that in the question - when I call GoogleSignInClient.revokeAccess(), I get a SIGN_IN_REQUIRED error, so I assume that I need to renew the authentication on the Google (not Firebase) side.

Comment: Done, thanks! I tried it without `silentSignIn()`, and I'm still getting SIGN_IN_REQUIRED when I do the actual call to `revokeccess()`. I edited the question to show the code for revoking access.

Comment: Are you sure the user is signed in? You need to sign in manually before you can use silentSignIn, hence that error. This [repo](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/blob/master/TypeANumber/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/tanc/MainActivity.java) might help.

Comment: That's where I'm not sure - I'm signed in _according to Firebase_. The order of operations is: 1) Sign in with Google, 2) Use that token to sign in with Firebase, 3) potentially wait a few days, 4) I'm still signed in with Firebase, 5) Create a `GoogleSignInClient` and call `revokeAccess`. Now I'm getting `SIGN_IN_REQUIRED` from Google.

Comment: As long as you get the error, I'm afraid you are not signed in. You say "I'm still signed in with Firebase", which is good, but that doesn't mean you are signed in with Google. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45075424/get-user-info-from-authentication-panel-in-firebase-console) might also help.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still where I started, you just confirmed where I am - 1) I'm logging in with Google to get credentials, 2) I'm logging into Firebase, 3) The Google credentials presumably expire after a while, but the Firebase credentials remain valid, 4) When the user chooses to revoke access, I want to revoke the Google credentials, but I can't do that without having the user sign into Google again, which is weird for the user since from the user's point of view, they were logged in the entire time (since Firebase is what the app is using, Google is just to get the token).

Comment: You say *Google credentials presumably expire*. Are you sure about that? How did you test that?

Comment: The fact that I'm getting `SIGN_IN_REQUIRED' when I call `revokeAccess()`. They were valid at some point since I was able to use them to create Firebase credentials. But that point could have happened a long time ago - days, or even weeks.

Comment: Have you checked if the user is really logged-in with Google before calling `revokeAccess()`?